# Bootstrap DropdownButton Hover too long

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue with the DropdownButton and I have no idea why the hover effect is longer than the actual size of the dropdown menu.
My DropdownButton is inside a Telerik Grid which may cause the problem. For the sake of simplicity I will attatch a screenshot and how I implement the DropdownButton. It would be way too much and too hard to understand if I post my entire Grid that I am using.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Another action</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">Something else here</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see is the hover effect too long:

[image: DropdownButton]

Comment: I suggest you post any custom CSS code you are using along with more HTML of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is related to the code that you posted. There must be something overwrite the default Bootstrap hover effect.

Try to add the below:

```
.dropdown-item:focus, .dropdown-item:hover{
  width: 100%;
}
```